# How add 3 lines to the graphic in xCharts?

Tags: javascript

How I can add 3 lines to the graphic in [xCharts](http://tenxer.github.com/xcharts/)? For make graphic with 2 lines I should write:

```
var data = {
    "xScale": "time",
    "yScale": "linear",
    "type": "line",
    "main": [
        {
            "data": getStatistic(), // Some JSON data
        },
    ],
    "comp": [
        {
            "type": "line",
            "data": getStatistic(), // Some JSON data
        },
    ],
};
```

But adding one more "comp" element doesn't work. On library website I not found graphic with more than two lines...

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be found here: https://github.com/tenXer/xcharts/issues/21

`main` data and `comp` are data both `Array`s. They can take many different data sets. The [documentation](http://tenxer.github.com/xcharts/docs/#data-main) might not explain this very well...

You can provide multiple data sets to the `main` Array to accomplish what you'd like. In example, here is how you might draw both pizza and tacos:

```
{
  "main": [
    {
      "className": ".pizza",
      "data": [
        {
          "x": "2012-11-05",
          "y": 12
        },
        {
          "x": "2012-11-06",
          "y": 8
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "className": ".tacos",
      "data": [
        {
          "x": "2012-11-05",
          "y": 8
        },
        {
          "x": "2012-11-06",
          "y": 11
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can add more data sets to this `main` Array. There is no limit.